# Scaling of single component (tlinestub) indepent of "bipole/length" scaling of other components?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

In the standard `circuitikz` settings, the `tlinestub` (open transmission line) seems a bit too large as compared to the standard transmission line `tline`. The scaling of all components can be done with the `bipoles/length` option, for all components or individually when passed as an option.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0)
 to[tline] (2,0) node[tlinestub] {};

\draw (4,0)
 to[tline] (6,0);

\ctikzset{bipoles/length=1cm} % change bipole length to scale tlinestub suitably
\node[tlinestub] at (6,0) {};
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=1.4cm} % reset to default value

% Alternative: \node[tlinestub,/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=1cm] at (6,0) {}; 

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

The left part demonstrates the standard scaling, while the right version has a *corrected* scaling factor. Is there an option to apply this scaling for all tlinestubs, at best relative to the `bipoles/length` setting?

[image]

Comment: This is clearly a bug; I'll fix it, but as a stopgap the solution by @frougon is ok.

Comment: @Rmano an additional note: the connections of the tline and tlinestub are somewhat inconsistent. for tline, it stops at the right circle outside, while for the tlinestub it continues right to the middle. should be the same, but i have no preference what looks better...

Comment: maybe there is even another thing to improve: the tlinestub could also be present in a flipped version to avoid the confusing perspective above (with a connection from the right and not from the left)

Comment: Yes --- it could be. I really do not like much this symbols (I prefer the plain rectangular ones, they're more "schematics"). I'll put that in the queue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that `every tlinestub node/.style={circuitikz/bipoles/length=1cm}` does what you want.

## Setting a fixed value for `bipoles/length`

The following example sets `bipoles/length` to `1cm` for all nodes of `tlinestub` shape:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\tikzset{every tlinestub node/.style={circuitikz/bipoles/length=1cm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
% Automatic way using the above \tikzset{every tlinestub node/.style={...}}:
\draw (0,0)
 to[tline] (2,0) node[tlinestub] {};

% Manual way from your example:
\draw (4,0)
 to[tline] (6,0);

\ctikzset{bipoles/length=1cm} % change bipole length to scale tlinestub suitably
\node[tlinestub] at (6,0) {};
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=1.4cm} % reset to default value

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

The change can also be done in a per-`circuitikz` -environment way:

```latex
\begin{circuitikz}[every tlinestub node/.style={circuitikz/bipoles/length=1cm}]

(...)

\end{circuitikz}
```

## Applying a scale factor to `bipoles/length`

Following your request in comments, if you want to have a given scale factor automatically applied to `bipoles/length` for all nodes of `tlinestub` shape, you can do this:

```latex
\makeatletter
\tikzset{every tlinestub node/.style={
   circuitikz/bipoles/length=〈factor〉\pgf@circ@Rlen}
}
\makeatother
```

(I didn't find a cleaner way to access the current value of `bipoles/length`: see `tex/generic/circuitikz/pgfcirc.defines.tex` around line 140.)

Here is a full example with scale factor 0.75. This seems to give the same size for `tlinestub` as for `tline`. Your `bipoles/length=1cm` would be obtained with scale factor 0.714 (approximation of 1/1.4), but this appears to be slightly too small.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{every tlinestub node/.style={
   circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.75\pgf@circ@Rlen}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (-1,0) to[tline] (2,0) node[tlinestub] {};

\ctikzset{bipoles/length=3cm}   % make it bigger
\draw[yshift=-1cm] (-1,0) to[tline] (2,0) node[tlinestub] {};

\ctikzset{bipoles/length=1.4cm} % restore the circuitikz default
\draw[yshift=-2cm] (-1,0) to[tline] (2,0) node[tlinestub] {};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: great! that solves my problem. In addition, is there any possibility though to set the length relative to the general `bipoles/length` instead of an absolute value? (would be more convenient to just change one variable for scaling, and no manual calculations)

Comment: Please see the latest edit, it should do what you want.

Comment: In the next version of `circuitikz`, there will be a generic method to achieve this, without side effects. This answer is (more or less) the best you can do now, +1. If you are curious, you can follow it on https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/255

Comment: yes, exactly. thanks a lot! @Rmano this looks promising indeed.